# Magento load product collection with all attributes

Tags: php, magento

I need to iterate over some products and access custom attributes, my code is:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'status', 'eq' => '1')))
    // more filters
    ->load();
```

then I have to:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    // here I can't access custom attributes
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    // here I can access them
}
```

and my problem is when I have a lot of products my script spends a lot of time in foreach loop. Can I somehow speed this by loading collection with all attributes?

Comment: Just post here, for me this is the one works`$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest all your attributes should go in flat tables.

So do some attributes setting like searchable, available in front end listing.

Then do an indexing.

Now when you get product collection you will get needed attributes and then code from there.

Instead of a loop loading each product you need to load a collection of products.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flat-tables, you have to add your custom attributes to the flat index. You can add them in the config.xml of the according module.
You can than skip the productload in the foreach which is probably causing the long processing time.

Answer (score -2):

What you are doing is not a good practice and should be avoided. You may try this

```
foreach($collection->getItems() as $item){

     echo $item->getName(); //$item is product instance. you can use it
}
```

### EDIT

In your question, you are doing a serious mistake and it should be avoided. That is what I am trying to point out through my answer.

See what you are doing here.

```
foreache($bigcollection as $singleone){
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
}
```

Basically you are loading a product inside a big for loop. It is a big mistake. Because if you do this, Magento need to do "extra fetching works" from database. **Do not use that method**. Through my solution, I showed you how to avoid loading a product inside a forloop. It is much reliable method.

If you dont want to use forloop, I think you need to edit your question and put that requirement there.

If you need to avoid for loop, you need to go for flat table concepts. That is the only one way that I know. Otherwise you cannot avoid a for each loop. :)

Comment: I can use it only for standard attributes. $item->getMyAwesomeAttributeAddedInBackendPanel() won't work.

Comment: you didn't specify it in your question and hence it's not my bad. If you are the one who down voted me, then first make your quesiton more clear :). I still believe this method is much more better than one you using

Comment: -> foreach loop comment "here I can't access custom attributes". Method might be better, but problem is loading products in loop which takes ages.

Comment: see my edit. If you dont want to use a for loop, you need to mention it in your question. I just tried to pointed out the wrong part of your question. Because it is general question and there may happen lot of views to your quesion. In that case, my answer has some importance. Hope you get me ! :)